# Should I use HttpWebRequest instead of SolrNet library to query Solr results?

Tags: vb.net, solrnet

I need to implement a search functionality with the ability to search for our internal and external applications which is currently using VB and .NET. We've been using google search appliances in the past but now we want to implement a similar search feature with the Solr search. I'm totally newbie to Solr but based on some search I found that there is API called SolrNet for .Net applications which we can use to query the Solr results.

I also found that SolrNet supports .Net framework 4.5 and above but we're still using 4.0... If that's true, Can someone guide if how to use SolrNet for the framework 4.0?

Also, if someone can help me understand the benefits of using the SolrNet APT instead of using HttpWebRequest? or if its possible to implement the Solr Search without using SolrNet API so there is no dependency on the framework? Please please provide some guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could just use HttpWebRequest, of course, but Solr can get complicated (it has numerous advanced features) and SolrNet really helps you model the search requests and responses correctly. If you did not use SolrNet you would need to write a lot of code to achieve the same result. Nothing wrong with that, if that's your jam, but for me, I find SolrNet saves me a lot of time. Also, SolrNet's codebase has been out for almost as long as Solr has been around, and the project has kept up with the times as Solr has added or modified features. It's a mature and active project, and I feel I can trust it to be around for years to come.

If you really are stuck with .NET 4.0, then I suppose you could use an earlier SolrNet release. Some of the earliest SolrNet releases (0.3.0, for instance) predate the release of .NET 4.5 in 2012. But... those early SolrNet releases may no longer be compatible with current versions of Solr, so "your mileage may vary" as they say.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your guidance. I'll give it a try with the earlier version of SolrNet but there is also another barrier that our company use VB, I've downloaded the Solr serach sample application(which is using SolrNet) from github which helped me to get started but that's using the C#. I used some freeware converters to convert the sample application to the VB but there is still lots of issues with the assemblies. Also, converters are not 100% accurate. Do you have sugegstion on that? Please advise.

Comment: SolrNet itself is just a library so of course you can use it with VB.Net

Comment: It's unfortunate that the samples are in C#, but how to convert C# to VB.Net with maximum fidelity is beyond the scope of your original question -- it has nothing to do with SolrNet per se. I'd try asking that as a separate question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'll post a separate question for the conversion related concerns.